# Lens Distortion not working with Unity 5.3.5

Tags: shaders, unity, virtual-reality

I have downloded the latest sdk from this link

https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk

I imported the package into my project.From the prefab added GvrMain to my scene and set the Distortion Correction to none as mentioned in the video below and edited the "GvrDistortion.cginc" shader .

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJVkdsZc9YA

But the lens distortion is not working for me. I have a dout that whether to edit the same folder or should create a new shader and include the existing shader file

I am using unity 5.3.5 and GoogleVRForUnity package